# What's the newline symbol in zsh's PS1?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to setup a multiple line PS1, for zsh, but `\n` doesn't was parsed by zsh,

`PS1="%~\n %> "`

How should I set it up?

Answer (score 97):

Use `$'\n'`

For example,

```
PROMPT="firstline"$'\n'"secondline "
```

or

```
NEWLINE=$'\n'
PROMPT="firstline${NEWLINE}secondline "
```

Comment: Worked just like I needed it too.

Comment: using NEWLINE makes it a lot easier to edit the prompt

Comment: What's the difference between PS1 and PROMPT variable?

Comment: @DidierA. PROMPT, and PROMPT2-4 are aliases of PS1-4 respectively, except that the PROMPT aliases "[do] not exist when the shell initializes in sh or ksh emulation mode."

Comment: Awesome. That works. Thanks a lot, buddy.

Answer (score 33):

```
PS1="firstline
secondline "
```

or

```
PS1=$'Hi Joe,\nwhat now?%# '
```

Taken from [FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html), item 3.13

Comment: This can cause problem. See the link. https://superuser.com/questions/382503/how-can-i-put-a-newline-in-my-zsh-prompt-without-causing-terminal-redraw-issues

Answer (score 3):

Like this (I know, looks awkward):

```
PS1="%~
 %> "
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for this as well. If you load prompinit (`autoload -Uz promptinit && promptinit`) you get the option for free: `$prompt_newline` which is `$'\n%{\r%}'`.

On a Debian system you can find the source code in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/promptinit` and/or https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Prompts/promptinit